# arg($1-e^{i\theta}$)

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Im trying to calculate arg($ 1-e^{i\theta} $) for a problem im trying to solve but I have run across a slight problem:

In this problem I have defined a branch cut to be $\mathbb{C}\setminus [1,\infty)$ so that arg:$z\rightarrow [0,2\pi)$

arg($1-e^{i\theta}$) to me would suggest that we are considering arg$((1-\cos\theta)-i\sin\theta)$ which could have 2 values, namely one in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and one in $[\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi)$

However here is the problem

Consider  $1-e^{i\theta}$ and let $\theta = 2\alpha$ such that $1-e^{i\theta} = 1-e^{2i\alpha} = e^{i\alpha}(e^{-i\alpha}-e^{i\alpha}) = -2i\sin(\alpha) e^{i\alpha}$

so clearly the modulus is $2\sin(\alpha)$ meaning that the argument would be $\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha$ but this is only one of the values I think it could be?

Another method would suggest after applying various identities that $\arctan(1-e^{i\theta}) = \arctan(\cot(\frac{\theta}{2}))$ hence the argument would be both as above and $\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\theta}{2}$ thus giving me the two solutions I spoke about.

Why does the first method lose a solution or the second method add an irrelevant second solution ?

Extra Note: Im looking to show that $\sqrt{1-e^{i\theta}} = (1-i)\sqrt{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}e^{i\frac{\theta}{4}}$ for $0<\theta<2\pi$ (according to the question).

However when I plug in my values I do not get this solution out.

Any guidance would be massively helpful

Comment: Have you tried drawing the path of $1-e^{i\theta}$? This is a wonderful exercise in isosceles triangles.

Comment: is it not just a circle around (1,0) oriented clockwise from (0,0) starting at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: It is a unit circle centered at $(1,0)$. $1-e^{i\theta}$ is a point with coordinates $(1-\cos\theta, -\sin\theta)$. If the slope of the line joining this point and the origin is $s$, then the required argument is $\tan^{-1} s$ for positive $s$ and $2\pi +\tan^{-1}s$ otherwise.

Comment: I agree with you on this! However looking at the extra note I dont see how these solutions actually give me the required answer- it seems as though the numbers dont work out and that there should only be one argument formula in the given region

Answer (score 2):

$$Z=1-e^{it}=1-\cos t-i \sin t= 2\sin^2 (t/2)-2i\sin (t/2) \cos (t/2)$$ $$=-2i \sin(t/2)[\cos(t/2)+i\sin(t/2)]=-2i\sin (t/2)e^{it/2}$$
$$\implies Z=2\sin(t/2) e^{-i\pi/2} e^{it/2},$$ if $0<t<2\pi$
So $$Arg(Z)=t/2-\pi/2$$
Next when $2\pi<t<4\pi$
$$Z=2\sin e^{i\pi/2} e^{it/2},$$ then
$$Arg(z)=t/2+\pi/2-2\pi=t/2-3\pi/2.$$

Here there are two things working together (i) the positivity/negativity of $\sin(t/2)$ and the fact that to keep $-\pi\le Arg(z)\le \pi$, we have to add $2n\pi, n\in I$

Comment: I have defined the holomorphic branch so that arg$(1-z) \in [0,2\pi)$ hence for the first calculation you would get arg$(Z) = 3\pi/2 + t/2$ which is where my confusion lies